# Boost.Python: Defining a constructor outside a class

Tags: constructor, factory, boost-python

Given a class:

```
class TCurrency {
    TCurrency();
    TCurrency(long);
    TCurrency(const std::string);
    ...
};
```

Wrapped with Boost.Python:

```
class_<TCurrency>( "TCurrency" )
    .def( init<long> )
    .def( init<const std::string&> )
    ...
    ;
```

Is it possible to create a factory method that appears as a constructor in Python:

```
TCurrency TCurrency_from_Foo( const Foo& ) { return TCurrency(); }
```

Such that in python:

```
bar = TCurrency(foo)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `make_constructor` (untested):

```
TCurrency* TCurrency_from_Foo( const Foo& ) { return new TCurrency(); }

class_<TCurrency>( "TCurrency" )
    .def( "__init__", boost::python::make_constructor( &TCurrency_from_Foo) )
;
```

The argument to make_constructor is any functor that returns a pointer[1] to the wrapped class.

[1] Actually, the function must return a the pointer holder type, so if your pointer holder is `boost::shared_ptr`, the function should return a boost::shared_ptr instead of a raw pointer.

Answer (score 0):

May be [my example](http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?9mgr6sa3roaf) helps you - init_python_object function can take any parameters that you need. Simple note: I define class_t with `boost::noncopyable and no_init`.